# How to get the root path of any package in Dart

Tags: dart, dart-pub, dart-io

I have the following project structure:

```
myproject_common
  - config
  - lib
myproject_server
  - bin
  - lib
myproject_client
  - lib
  - web
```

`myproject_common` library has config.yaml file in its `config` folder. I need to get a path (URI object) to that file from `myproject_server` to parse it.

The only way I see is to use smth like:

```
// "../../" - go back from /bin folder to root folder where my own packages located.
Platform.script.resolve('../../myproject_common/configs/config.yaml')
```

But is looks like a hack and risk-prone.

Answer (score 2):

The `lib` folder is the only folder intended to be accessed from another package. You should move your `config` folder to `lib/config` then you can access the file reliably through the `packages` folder.

Comment: No, I think it's a bad idea to keep configuration files in `lib` folder. Perhaps I'd better move this folder to server.